# Detail form not sync with ADF tree based on a single recursive view object

Tags: oracle-adf

I am working on form having a tree based on a single recursive view object, I have created a tree and a detail form which are based on the same recursive view object.
 
 The problem is when the page runs, It synchronize the detail form only with the top most tree nodes. When I select any sub-node in the tree, the details form is not showing the selected record.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tree binding (adf bindings file), you should set your 'Target Data Source' attribute to point to your iterator:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/50-synchromize-form-treeselection-169192.pdf

https://technology.amis.nl/2008/09/23/nice-little-feature-in-adf-11g-target-data-source-attribute-on-tree-binding-helps-synchronize-page-with-tree-node-selection/

Comment: I do that, but it not work with all levels of the tree. it just work with a parent node ... i think the problem is with the recursive node rule

Comment: I remember using this solution in the past without problems.

Comment: Have you tried the example from second link I provided? Is that working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario, and solved it with a secondary instance of the same VO and building the form upon that. how ever I added some code to Selection listener of the tree to make the synchronization. the adf ow to paper No. 50 also helped me a lot.

```
        Utilities.invokeEL("#{bindings.PlnFormTitle.treeModel.makeCurrent}", new Class[] { SelectionEvent.class },
                       new Object[] { selectionEvent });

    RowKeySet addedSet = selectionEvent.getAddedSet();
    Iterator it = addedSet.iterator();
    List<Key> keyList = (List<Key>) it.next();
    Key k = keyList.get(keyList.size() - 1);

    OperationBinding setCurrentRowWithKey = commonBindingOperation.getOperatioBinding("setCurrentRowWithKey");
    setCurrentRowWithKey.getParamsMap().put("rowKey", k.toStringFormat(true));

    setCurrentRowWithKey.execute();
```

this code is what I used for synchronization.